# How to use viewHolder to make listView user input not go back to default when scrolling off screen

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listView where a user can enter input to change the textView on each listView row. When you scroll the row off the screen the edited text goes away and the default text reappears. I know this is fixed with the viewHolder but I can't get it to work in my custom adapter class.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> Chores = new ArrayList<>();
        //Chores.add("");

        final ListAdapter MyAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Chores);
        ListView listViewObject = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customListView_ID);
        listViewObject.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        listViewObject.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    String ChoreString = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));




                }
            }

        );
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ID);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chores.add("");
                ((ArrayAdapter)MyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });




    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.emilythacker.chorelist.R.id.textView_ID;



class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> choreText;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
        this.choreText = choreText;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        //final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(textView_ID);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textView_ID);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(choreText.get(position));
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
                input.setHint("hint");
                alertDialog.setView(input);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Set Chore");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




                        holder.textView.setText(input.getText().toString());





                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });



        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton imageButton;
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.emilythacker.chorelist.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/customListView_ID"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Add Chore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_ID" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

custon_listview_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_ID"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:text="Click here to add chore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ID"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton_ID"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When text is entered into the edit text, you need to save it to a variable associated with that position, and in getView you need to set the text of the editText to that position's value.  Otherwise you'll just have whatever random value was in there last.

Basically, any value that can change in a row's UI must be saved and written to it in getView.

Comment: I don't see how I'm not doing that? This viewHolder approach is very confusing to me.

Comment: @RyderThacker so dont use view holder pattern as in 90% of cases it is almost useless - it only makes more hassle (in fact none of the std google's `ListView` adapaters use that pattern)

Comment: @RyderThacker No you aren't.  You're setting it to the text view but you are NOT saving it in a variable and using that to reset it in getView  Remember that evry time the user scrolls an item on/off screen that any view based variabes are lost-  saving it in the view is NOT sufficient

Comment: @pskink The value of the view holder pattern is to store the views of a row in a variable so you don't have to use constant findViewByIds.  That actually is very useful for perf reasons, to the point where anything that doesn't use it or an equivalent pattern is wrong.  The reason why Google's adapters don't use it is that they didn't think of the pattern until after those were developed.  Notice their newer classes like RecycerView all do use it.

Comment: @GabeSechan those two or three `findViewById` is nothing compared to what is done when you scroll up/down the list view, i made some measurements and it turned out that i saved one or two ms when scrolling 1000 item list view from top to bottom, does it really pay off? i dont think so (maybe there is 10% of cases where you dont have two or three child views per item but 10 or twenty and the difference is more visible), the similar results are [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html),

Comment: @pskink if that's all you saved you have a trivial list.  Most lists have far more than 2 or 3 views, and they have various handlers and other objects that need to be placed in the holder or recreated.  It is a major perf issue on non-trivial implementations.

Comment: @GabeSechan so i made another layout, this time with 20 views (is it non trivial?) again called `findViewById` x 20 and to simulate top-bottom scrolling called everything 1000 times, so the total number of `findViewById`s was 20k and the total time spent was now 30-40ms (which is 5 times smaller than blink of the eye), i am still considering that pattern as a "premature optimization" which is the root of ...